# Display a string, vector<int> map in C++

Tags: c++, dictionary

I have the following map :

```
std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > my_map;
```

I insert keys and values in my map this way :

```
my_map.insert( std::pair<std::string, std::vector<int> >(nom,vect) );
```

How can I print both keys and values of my map ?

I've already tested :

```
for( std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >::iterator ii=my_map.begin(); ii!=my_map.end(); ++ii)
    {
        std::cout << (*ii).first << ": " << (*ii).second << std::endl;
    }
```

But for some reason i get this error :

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>’ and ‘std::vector<int>’)
std::cout << (*ii).first << ": " << (*ii).second << std::endl;
```

Comment: How can you print a `std::vector<int>`? You cant, unless you define how it is supposed to be printed by providing an overload for the `operator<<`

Comment: You'll need to iterate over the `std::vector<int>`, either by doing it in-place, or by overloading `operator<<` for this type (which I don't recommend.)

Comment: Damn I'm a beginner, I really don't get the need for every commentator on this forum to downvote a post when they find the answer is obvious

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, but keep in mind that `std::map` not a hash table.

Comment: you got my downvote, not because the answer is obvious, but because imho it would have been easy to find out that the error is not related to the `string` and `vector` beeing in a `map`. For example you could have tried to print a `vector` to the screen that is not inside a `map`. However, dont worry, I usually get lots of downvotes on my questions/answers ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, use `typedef` (or more modern method `using`):

```
typedef std::vector<int> ivector;
typedef std::map<std::string,ivector> sivmap;

sivmap my_map;

// now benefits of using synonyms
my_map.insert( sivmap::value_type(nom,vect) );

// or even easier
my_map.insert( std::make_pair(nom,vect) );

// for loop is less verbose as well
// when there is no intention to modify data use const_iterator
for( sivmap::const_iterator ii=my_map.begin(); ii!=my_map.end(); ++ii)
{
    std::cout << ii->first << ": " << ii->second << std::endl;
}
```

now for your loop to work create operator

```
std::ostream &<<( std::ostream &out, const ivector &iv )
{
     out << '[';
     for( ivector::const_iterator it = iv.begin(); it != iv.end(); ++it ) {
         if( it != iv.begin() ) out << ", ";
         out << *it;
     }
     return out << ']';
 }
```

This will not only make your code shorter and less verbose, but less error prone and easier to read and modify

Comment: I'm not a big fan of defining the output operator for a `using` typedef. It sends a false message of defining it for a separate type, when it's just an alias. A different output routine with another alias would clash with this.

Comment: @TheVee This is just an example, it can be easily changed to template, which will work with any vector, I just did not want to push to match information to OP at once.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that is because there is no `operator<<` for a `std::vector<int>`, making this one of the rarer kind of C++ compile errors that are quite comprehensible and concise. Just like you wrote your own output for the `std::map` using an iterator, you'll need to do something similar for the `std::vector`.

One reason why the standard does not do this for us is the boundless variety of formats that people may be expecting the output to appear in. For example, if you want the data surrounded by a `(` and `)` and each two elements separated by a `,` and a space, it's easier to ask you as the user to implement this in a few lines than to make an algorithm that allows that but also printing each element on a separate line with alignment on a decimal point and with indentation for recursive printing of vectors of vectors, which someone else may want.

For the same reason it's recommendable to format your vector in the place where you need it, rather than actually implement and `operator<<` for it. If you are going to use the same printing mechanism for the same kind of vectors in multiple points in your program, and want to be able to write it nicely as `std::cout << vector << '\n'`, the best way is to create a class publicly extending a `std::vector<int>`, as in

```
class printable_vector : public std::vector<int> {

  using std::vector<int>::vector; // inherit constructors
  // (all other public member functions are inherited automatically)

  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const printable_vector& vector) {
    // do the actual printing to os...
    return os;
  }
};
```

That way you can operate a `printable_vector` in any way you could a normal `std::vector<int>` but it also offers the output functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add another for bucle to solve that problem:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> > my_map;

    string nom = "carlitos";
    vector<int> vect;

    vect.push_back(1);
    vect.push_back(2);
    vect.push_back(3);
    vect.push_back(4);


    my_map.insert( std::pair<std::string, std::vector<int> >(nom,vect) );

    for( std::map<std::string, std::vector<int> >::iterator ii=my_map.begin(); ii!=my_map.end(); ++ii)
    {
     for( std::vector<int>::iterator iii=(*ii).second.begin(); iii!=(*ii).second.end(); ++iii)
     {
        std::cout << (*ii).first << ": " << *iii << std::endl;
     }
    }
}
```

[Test!](http://ideone.com/MAmQC3)

(this is because `std::cout` won't print a `std::vector` directly, through the operator `<<`)